# What's wrong with this implementation of the DataList repeater?

Tags: datalist

I have the following declarative in an *ascx* which displays a 4 column list of file names. The file names are *xlxs* files that can be downloaded so the command event is called when the file name is clicked.

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dlHistoricalRates" RepeatColumns="4" >
    <HeaderStyle>
    </HeaderStyle>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <span>Historial Rates</span>
    </HeaderTemplate>        
    <ItemTemplate>           
        <asp:LinkButton id="historicalRate" ClientIDMode="Static" 
          runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("filename") %>' 
          CommandName="Download" OnCommand="historicalRate_OnCommand" >
              <%# Eval("filename") %>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>        
</asp:DataList>
```

The code-behind command code:

```
protected void historicalRate_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument != null)
        {
            historicalRate_Download(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                    
        }                
    }
}
```

But the `CommandArgument` is an empty string when it should be the file name. I know the express `Eval()` is working as it display the file names in the control.

Why, is the `filename` not being passed as the `CommandArgument`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CommandArgument` looks fine but another way for getting LinkButton's arg from `sender` object:

```
protected void historicalRate_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // get the reference of clicked LinkButton
    LinkButton lb = sender as LinkButton;
    string cmd = lb.CommandName;
    string arg = lb.CommandArgument;

    if (cmd == "Download")
    {
        if (arg != null)
        {
            historicalRate_Download(arg);                    
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ali - The arg is still and empty string.

Comment: try it in `OnClick` event of LinkButton and see.